# Jquery autocomplete not showing suggestions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am a newbie in web development and is trying to learn some jquery. I was trying to populate some auto complete suggestions, but it is not working, this the script I used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#category").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:8080/fun/getCat2",
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                    data: {query : request.term},
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    },
                    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                        alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.label);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

This is the response from the web service:

```
[
    {
        "label": "asdfsadf",
        "value": "1"
    },
    {
        "label": "wrtwetr",
        "value": "2"
    }
]
```

When I send request from postman I am getting JSON response, but not from the web ui end and I am not getting any error.

Comment: what response do you get from the web ui

Comment: i am not getting any suggestions, not even an error

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Setautocomplete();
});

Function Setautocomplete() {
    $("#category").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/fun/getCat2",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-.   form-urlencoded'
                },
                data: {
                    query: request.term
                },
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                },
                onSelect: function(suggestion) {
                    alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.label);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am not an expert in web development. can you provide an example?

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: @Adriaan I totally Understood. This was answered 5 years back and I am trying to make it readable and I will add details to this for any further readers ASAP.